# How to aggregate results of search engines using drupal

Tags: search

I want to develop a site with Drupal 7 that lists the search results of some popular search engines. Is there any module or I should develop a custom module for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you have links to RSS feeds, you can use the [Aggregator](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/aggregator) module that comes with Drupal; the alternative is the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/feeds) module.
Otherwise, if you want to import the content as nodes, you can use the [Feed Import](http://drupal.org/node/1360374) module.

Comment: I think that you do not get me. For example consider that we have some software download site and I want to aggregate the search result of those sites and list them into my site.